# rsync compare destination issues

Tags: rsync

**Update for Clarity** I want to sync two directories - a desktop folder & external hard drive. Additionally, I want to copy all the new/changed files between the source directory (desktop folder) & destination (external hard drive) to a third location.

I have tried: `rsync -bauvn --compare-dest /thirddirectory /desktopfolder/ /externalharddrive`

As explained in the comments, when I do this I get the correct list of changed files, but it copies to the external hard drive instead of the third directory.

I have also tried:
`rsync -bauvn --compare-dest /externalharddrive /desktopfolder/ /thirddirectory`
When I do this, even if it is right after I run `rsync -bauv /desktopfolder/ /externalharddrive` I get a long file list to copy to the third directory, instead of just the differences.

Any help making an accurate third directory using rsync that only copies the differences between the desktop folder & the external hard drive would be greatly appreciated!! (Thanks for your help already roaima!!)

OLD

---

I am trying to backup my data using rsync. I am new to this, so I need all the help I can get. In a typical year, I go through 8 TB of data on my 500gb macbook. I mainly deal with package files. I do not have administrator access to the computer. Our IT department could potentially help me with a one time change, but right now that may be out of the question. (for purposes of updating rsync etc.)

I have had success syncing my macbook folder with the master folder on a 4tb external hard drive. However, to be safe I like to copy the new files to the cloud on box or google drive. Since I typically deal with package files, copying the new/changed files to a third destination would be ideal because I could then zip them up and upload to cloud. Package files do not do well if they are not zipped in regards to box & drive.

Copying from macbook to external drive folder, rsync works like a charm. I use `rsync -bauvn .../Desktop/20-21\ Mac \ Folder/ /Volumes/Jack\ Passport/20-21\ Passport\ Folder`

When trying to use --compare-dest I use `rsync -bauvn --compare-dest /Volumes/Jack\ Passport/20-21\ Passport\ Folder .../Desktop/20-21\ Mac \ Folder/ .../123dest`

When I use --compare-dest I get different results: a much longer list of files get copied than when I simply copy from macbook to external drive.

Even if I have to do this a different way, where I use the file list from macbook to external drive syncing or something like that to copy files to a third location I am completely fine with it.

I just want a way where at the end of the day I can copy files from my mac to the hard drive with a push of a button, and then with another push of the button I have a folder of items I need to zip & upload to the cloud. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know the `-n` flag is `--dry-run`, which means "don't actually write any files"?

Comment: You've specified `-b` (`--backup`) but no `--backup-dir`, so it's ignored. You could use this to create a set of files for uploading to your Cloud storage that were replaced in your external disk backup. This way you'd get (G)FS-style backups. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes I've tried without the -n just figured I would add that in for purpose of recreating issue. I thought -b would just backup with the default suffix of ~. I was including this because I don't want the old versions to be totally overwritten without a trace. Would setting a --backup-dir copy new/changed files to the backup directory location?

Comment: My issue is basically that the --compare-dest is coming up with a different list than when I just use -bauvn. Interestingly enough when I do `rsync -bauvn --compare-dest /thirddestination /desktopfolder/ /externalharddrive` I get the correct file list, but it copies the file to the external hard drive as opposed to the 'third destination' folder

Comment: That's what you've told it to do. The copy in this command is from `/desktopfolder` to `/externalharddrive`, omitting files that are already up-to-date in the `/thirddestination`. At the moment the issue in your question seems to be you're getting different (longer) lists of files. From your comment just now it seems that's a side-effect of what you actually want to do. If you update your question explaining what it is you want to achieve, someone (or I) should be able to help you out.

Comment: I've added updates above. Thanks for your help thus far!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make an accurate third directory (`/thirddirectory`) that only copies the differences between the desktop folder (`/desktopfolder`) and the external hard drive `/externalharddrive`.

This is straightforward enough, but as you've found, you can't update the external hard drive at the same time.

```
rsync -av --compare-dest=/externalharddrive /desktopfolder/ /thirddirectory
```

You have a few options at this point, but no matter how you slice and dice this you are going to have problems using `rsync` to identify files that have been removed from your source. In turn this means your backup will not be representative of the state of `/desktopfolder`

1. You can use `--write-batch` (and conversely `--read-batch`) generate a batch of changes that can be fed into `rsync` at a later date. Trying to recover files from this directly is impossible, though, so probably not so good for backing up.
2. You can use `/externalharddrive` as a backup for files in `/thirddirectory` that are updated from `/desktopfolder`. The files on the external hard drive that you then take elsewhere are one step removed from the current backup, so this may not be ideal. However, it's probably the easiest

   rsync -av --backup --backup-dir=/externalharddrive /desktopfolder/ /thirddirectory
3. You identify the set of differences, update those changes, and use the original set of differences to determine the files to be saved elsewhere. The code uses GNU extensions to handle file names with non-printing characters such as newlines

   ```
    diffdir1() { ( cd "$1" && find . -type f -printf "%s\t%T+\t%y\t%#m\t%U\t%G\t%p\0" | LC_ALL=C sort -z ); }

    comm -z -23 <(diffdir1 /desktopfolder) <(diffdir1 /externalharddrive) |
        cut -z -f7- |
        rsync -av --from0 --files-from - /desktopfolder /thirddirectory

    comm -z -23 <(diffdir1 /desktopfolder) <(diffdir1 /externalharddrive) |
        cut -z -f7- |
        rsync -av --from0 --files-from - /desktopfolder /externalharddrive
   ```

   You can avoid the obvious race condition by capturing the output of `diffdir1 /desktopfolder` in a file or variable and using that as input to both `comm` commands.
4. Stop trying to use `rsync` and instead consider something like `borg`. Of all the options this is probably the most promising

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Maybe I am incorrect in the purpose of rsync & that is why you are steering me against it, but I wanted to clarify a few things as I am not sure that I communicated them well enough. Here's what I want my work flow to look like. Say I am starting with /externalharddrive and /desktopfolder as perfectly mirrored locations. The next day, I have a new list of files in a myriad of locations inside /desktopfolder. I use `rsync -bauv` to copy the files quickly to the hard drive. I want to sync these new/changed files to /thirdlocation so I can zip them & upload to cloud

Comment: After I do this, I would delete the files from /desktopfolder. The next day, when I have more new/changed files, it is my impression & experience that `rsync -bauv /desktopfolder/ /externalharddrive` should simply copy those new/changed files to the external hd. If I could then type a new rsync command to copy the new/changed files to /thirdlocation it would allow me to zip them & upload them to cloud for added protection. Is this possible?

Comment: You no longer want rsync